# boto3 can't connect over SSO

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm having trouble getting a boto3 client to connect to AWS over SSO. I can sign in and query with the CLI tool:

```bash
aws sso login --profile my-profile
aws s3 ls  # this works
```

But when I try to access through boto3, following the top rated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62311866/how-to-use-the-aws-python-sdk-while-connecting-via-sso-credentials), I get an `UnauthorizedSSOTokenError`:

```py
import boto3
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='my-profile')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.list_buckets()  # this fails
```

What's going on here? Am I not using boto3 correctly?