# Sign in to AWS with SSO using Boto3 (without credentials file pre-configured)

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-sdk

I am trying to create a package/application that when given correct SSO credentials can log-in to an AWS S3 bucket.

The answers to this question [How to use the AWS Python SDK while connecting via SSO credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62311866/how-to-use-the-aws-python-sdk-while-connecting-via-sso-credentials) assumes a credentials files. However, I had hoped to be able to run my application on any PC as long as the person who runs it has an AWS account registered with the Start URL.

How I would normally need to set this up is to do:

```
aws configure sso
# Run through the configuration steps here
```

then do

```py
import boto3
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='sso_profile')
client = boto3.client('s3')
```

On a fresh machine, aws cli would not be available and I would like to do everything through boto3.

2ps's answered for [How to use the AWS Python SDK while connecting via SSO credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62311866/how-to-use-the-aws-python-sdk-while-connecting-via-sso-credentials) got me far, However I do not know what the "account_id" will be for any given user.

Comment: If this is a public package/app and the account will change depending on the user, you do need to ask for a minimal amount of information that is not guessable.

Even  `aws configure sso` asks for information, although it does fill in some eventually after a few steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I do not know what the "account_id" will be for any given user.

`account_id` is not required in ~.aws/config.

You can make it an input from the user.

```
[?] Please enter account ID:
 >
```

Or you can use [sso list-account](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sso/client/list_accounts.html) to list the accounts present in the user's SSO.

```
[?] Please select the account to use:
  Prd [123456789] <
  Acc [987654321]
  Dev [786234823]
```

And since user can have multiple Role per AWS Account, if there are multiple roles, you can use `list-account-roles` and have the user select which role to use for the account they entered.

Comment: Using this and 2ps's response from the other question I was able to put together something. Thank you so much. Once I get time I will put together a comprehensive answer for my question