# Can AWS SSO tokens be refreshed (by doing a browser login) automatically?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, sdk, single-sign-on, aws-cli

I have a Ruby application using the AWS SDK Ruby v3, and recent I've added support for using SSO profiles instead of static "key ID + secret" configuration.

The new setup works well for a while, until the token "expires" and I start getting `Aws::Errors::InvalidSSOToken` exceptions, at which point the user needs to manually run the CLI's `aws sso login` to get a browser login screen.

I would have liked to skip the manual AWS CLI running step - if the SDK can directly do the `aws sso login` step (with the correct profile).

I can probably do `exec` with the correct arguments - but I would like to do it "the SDK way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Beware: terrible hacks ahead!

This is my currently complete (unless I find bugs and/or people suggest changes) and working implementation of Ruby code that renews the SSO token without using the AWS CLI, and in a way that is compatible with the AWS Ruby SDK version 3 (as of this writing). It doesn't auto-launches the user's browser, but that is a good thing because the Python `browsers` extension has a few bugs...

Kudus to [@tsal-troser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22277802/tsal-troser) that, at his own answer, pointed at the Python example that was used to create this sample code, and [@2ps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6043170/2ps) that wrote that Python code.

```
require 'aws-sdk-core'

class SSOConfig
    class Error < StandardError
    end
    
    def initialize profile = nil
        profile = 'default' if profile.to_s.empty?
        @profile = profile
        raise "No AWS config file found!" unless File.exists? "#{ENV['HOME']}/.aws/config"
        @config = File.readlines("#{ENV['HOME']}/.aws/config").collect(&:chomp)
        @profile_config = @config.select do |l| 
            (l =~ /^\[profile #{@profile}\]$/ .. l =~ /^(?!\[profile #{@profile}\])(\[|$)/) ? true : false
        end[...-1]
        raise Error, "Failed to find session for profile #{profile!}" if session.to_s.empty?
        @session_config = @config.select do |l| 
            (l =~ /^\[sso-session '?#{session}'?\]$/ .. l =~ /^(?!\[sso-session '?#{session}'?\])(\[|$)/) ? true : false
        end[...-1]
        raise Error, "Failed to find SSO session configuration!" if @session_config.empty?
    end
    
    def session
        return @sdk_session unless @sdk_session.nil?
        @sdk_session = @profile_config.select do |l|
            l =~ /^sso_session/
        end.collect do |l|
            (l.split /\s*=\s*/).last
        end.first
    end
    
    def start_url
        return @sdk_start_url unless @sdk_start_url.nil?
        @sdk_start_url = @session_config.select do |l|
            l =~ /^sso_start_url/
        end.collect do |l|
            (l.split /\s*=\s*/).last
        end.first
    end
    
    def account_id
        return @sdk_account_id unless @sdk_account_id.nil?
        @sdk_account_id = @profile_config.select do |l|
            l =~ /^sso_account_id/
        end.collect do |l|
            (l.split /\s*=\s*/).last
        end.first
    end
    
    def region
        'us-east-1' # can we use other regions?
    end
    
    def client_name
        'SSOClientName'
    end

    def try_renew_token
        puts "SSO token has expired! Trying to re-authorize SSO session..."
        oidc_client = Aws::SSOOIDC::Client.new(region: self.region)
        creds = oidc_client.register_client(client_name: self.client_name, client_type: 'public')
        auth = oidc_client.start_device_authorization(
            client_id: creds.client_id,
            client_secret: creds.client_secret,
            start_url: self.start_url)
        puts "Verification code: #{auth.user_code}"
        puts "Open your browser with this url: #{auth.verification_uri_complete}"
        puts "When complete, press ENTER here"
        STDIN.getch; puts ""
        token = oidc_client.create_token(
            grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code', 
            device_code: auth.device_code,
            client_id: creds.client_id,
            client_secret: creds.client_secret)
        sso_client = Aws::SSO::Client.new(region: self.region)
        account_roles = sso_client.list_account_roles(
            access_token: token.access_token,
            account_id: self.account_id)
        role = account_roles.role_list.first
        role_creds = sso_client.get_role_credentials(
            role_name: role.role_name,
            account_id: role.account_id,
            access_token: token.access_token)
        # update the global config credentials, in case someone creates a default client
        # or actually uses the global credentials
        Aws.config[:credentials] = Class.new do
            include Aws::CredentialProvider
            def initialize creds
                @creds = creds
            end
            def credentials
                Aws::Credentials.new(@creds.access_key_id, @creds.secret_access_key, @creds.session_token)
            end
        end.new(role_creds.role_credentials)
        # hack SSOTokenProvider to update the token on disk
        # the real SSOTokenProvider will check that file first before trying to refresh
        Class.new(Aws::SSOTokenProvider) do
            def refresh
            # This is called by SSOTokenProvider.initialize and will fail with a stale token file
            # so just ignore it in our hack
            end
        end.new(sso_session: self.session, sso_region: self.region).send :update_token_cache, {
            'startUrl' => self.start_url,
            'region' => self.region,
            'accessToken' => token.access_token,
            'clientId' => creds.client_id,
            'clientSecret' => creds.client_secret,
            'expiresAt' => Time.at(Time.now.tv_sec + token.expires_in).utc,
            'registrationExpiresAt' => Time.at(Time.now.tv_sec + token.expires_in).utc,
            'refreshToken' => token.refresh_token,
        }
        true
    end
end
```

Usage: when catching an `Aws::Errors::InvalidSSOToken`, call `SSOConfig.new("your-profile").try_renew_token`. After the call returns successfully, `Aws.config[:credentials]` is loaded with a credential provider that will return the correct credentials, and also the token cache on disk has been updated - so existing clients should continue working by refreshing from the disk cache.

For example:

```rb
begin
  # try to do some AWS work
rescue Aws::Errors::InvalidSSOToken => e
  retry if SSOConfig.new("your-profile").try_renew_token
  $stderr.puts "SSO token expired - cannot renew!"
end
```

###### Worries:

1. Big hack: the SSO token cache logic is private to the `SSOTokenProvider` and there is no way to manipulate it directly (or get `SSOTokenProvider` to refresh it itself, once it has expired). So in order to update the disk cache, we both need to instantiate a purposefully broken `SSOTokenProvider` (otherwise it won't instantiate) and then call its private methods directly. Fun!
2. Small hack: I can't find a way to use a "real" `CredentialProvider` for `Aws.config[:credentials]`, so we use an anonymous class.
3. There is no error checking, except basic sanity checks that we can read the configuration - which throws instead of returning `false`.
4. The new token lifetime seems awfully short - 28800 seconds. A login with the AWS CLI lasts for days. I think the problem is that the token we get from `create_token` doesn't have a refresh token so `SSOTokenProvider` can't refresh it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You can add an error handler when you get `InvalidSSOToken` then do an SSO authentication.

I've never tried the SDK way. I've tried the `exec` cli command `aws sso login` (because it's easier). It will create a `cache.json` file with the `token` and `expiresAt` values.

This is the project I used as a reference: https://github.com/NeilJed/aws-sso-credentials/blob/master/awssso

Here's the part you can use as reference for checking if the token is expired. https://github.com/NeilJed/aws-sso-credentials/blob/master/awssso#L110-L137

Here's another example of doing it via SDK but in Python:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71850591/22277802

Comment: Following the Python code in the stack overflow answer you linked, I came up with some initial work (that, due to not fitting in a comment I submitted as another WIP answer). I haven't completed it or integrated it into my own project, but the I did some initial testing and it looks promising.